# Dockerfile MKDIR not working (node:alpine)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am getting error when trying to create /app directory using the files below. This has worked for me in the past so I am not sure what is going wrong now:

```
Step 1/8 : FROM node:alpine
 ---> 0d8a3475dbc3
Step 2/8 : RUN MKDIR -p "/app"
 ---> Running in ad24819ce982
/bin/sh: MKDIR: not found
ERROR: Service 'add_delete_server' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c MKDIR -p "/app"' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Docker compose :

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  add_delete_server:
    
    build:
      context: ./AddDeleteServer
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app
```

Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM node:alpine

#setting work directory
RUN MKDIR -p "/app"
WORKDIR "/app"

#copying only package.json first, so cache can be used for minor changes
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install

# copy rest of files
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run","dev"]
```

But I am not able to generate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MKDIR` is not a command ,`mkdir` is the command

Comment: add_delete_server_1  | npm ERR! code ENOENT
add_delete_server_1  | npm ERR! syscall open
add_delete_server_1  | npm ERR! path /app/package.json
add_delete_server_1  | npm ERR! errno -2
add_delete_server_1  | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
add_delete_server_1  | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

Comment: I believe is on your volumes the app folder must be on AddDeleteServer dir seems like node cant find the right files to start the process, maybe are misplaced